# события, слоты, сигналы в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, интерфейс

Есть кнопка. При наведении курсора на нее она меняет фон, и при нажатии на нее она меняет фон. Когда курсор наводится на нее, она имеет обычный фон.
Как сделать следующее:

1. При нажатии на кнопку, она изменила свой фон на *Pressed* (кнопка
       не отпущена), затем
2. При отводе курсора кнопка принимала обычный
       фон (кнопка не отпущена), затем
3. При наведении на кнопку, она
       изменила свой фон на *Pressed*

**Одним словом, реализовать такую же реакцию для кнопки, как у навигационных кнопках Windows.**

Ето мой код:

```
    void enterEvent(QEvent *)
    {
       this->setIcon( QIcon(Hover));
    }

    void leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        this->setIcon( QIcon(Normal));
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        this->setIcon( QIcon(Pressed) );

    }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        this->setIcon( QIcon(Hover));
    }
```

После нажатия на кнопку (кнопка не отпущена), при отводе курсора кнопка не принимает обычный фон. В этом и проблема.

Comment: А в чем проблема? что у вас конкретно не работает?

Comment: Не совсем понятно (а точнее совсем не понятно) в чём вопрос?

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку (кнопка не отпущена), при отводе курсора кнопка не принимает обычный фон. В этом и проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить метод:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    if( 0 <= e->pos().x() &&
        e->pos().x() <= this->width() &&
        0 <= e->pos().y() &&
        e->pos().y() <= this->height() )
    {
        this->setIcon( QIcon(Pressed));
    }
    else
    {
        this->setIcon( QIcon(Normal));
    }
}
```